# What is the difference between pdump and pbootstrap?

Tags: build

I recently built emacs from the source code and I have some questions about portable dump.

Building process generates `bootstrap-emacs.pdmp` and `emacs.pdmp` successively in the last part of building. After that, it executes `cp -f emacs.pdmp bootstrap-emacs.pdmp` to overwrite it.

My questions are

1. What is the difference between `pdump` and `pbootstrap` method?
2. Why does building process generates two different dump files, although it will be overwritten soon after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the Elisp Reference Manual which has a helpful section on "Building Emacs" in appendix E1: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Building-Emacs.html.

There you learn that `bootstrap-emacs.pdmp` is an intermediate step:

> used while bootstrapping Emacs, when no previous Emacs binary and no *.elc byte-compiled Lisp files are available.

Of course, you can read this from the comfort of yr own emacs: `C-h R elisp`.

As @Drew said earlier today: *Ask Emacs*!

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm going to check the manual.